# Express.js possible to set both localhost:3000 and localhost:3000/ as different routes?

Tags: node.js, express

The question basically is Is there a way to set both of these routes localhost:3000 and localhost:3000/ to return different stuff?

I have been trying to set 2 different paths for localhost:3000 and localhost:3000/. But when I use curl to localhost:3000 express will always pad the url to localhost:3000/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't, as `http://localhost:3000` is just a short syntax for `http://localhost:3000/`, hence the two routes do not differ at all.

It's a different thing with `http://localhost:3000/foo` and `http://localhost:3000/foo/`, where the former denotes a file, and the latter a directory.